# Join lines together that do not end in a comma

Tags: csv, awk, sed, tr, solaris-10

I have a CSV file produced by MS Excel. Where merged cells exist in the original spreadsheet, the original rows containing these become multi-line in the CSV output. I would like to join these back into one line.

I am looking for a Unix (Solaris 10) tool (sed/awk/tr etc) that will join all lines not ending in a comma to the next line, while leaving all lines that end in a comma untouched. The newline character at the end of lines not ending in a comma would be replaced with a space.

E.g. If the input file contains:

```
,Dilbert,
,,Wally,
Alice,
Asok9
Dogbert:
Catbert,
Ratbert,
```

Then the resulting output will be:

```
,Dilbert,
,,Wally,
Alice,
Asok9 Dogbert: Catbert,
Ratbert,
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk '{printf "%s"(/,$/?RS:FS),$0}' file
,Dilbert,
,,Wally,
Alice,
Asok9 Dogbert: Catbert,
Ratbert,
```

If line ends with `,` use `RS` (Record Selector is default new line)
If no, use `FS` (Field Separator is default one space)

Comment: Wow, that was quick. I love the logic of this, but it doesn't work on my system. I get the error message `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1`. Unfortunately I don't have gawk available, so just using the standard awk that comes with Solaris 10. Do you know of a way of converting this to syntax that that version of awk will recognise?

Comment: While looking at the man page for awk to see if there was assistance there, I noticed under the `SEE ALSO` section `nawk(1)`. I used `nawk` instead of `awk`, and got exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much. Very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed ':a
/,$/ b
$ b
N;s/\n/ /;b a' YourFile
```

same trick with sed, change `/,$/` by `/, *$/` if some trailing space are present

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. That also works well on my input file.